# Cloud Foundry for isolated environments

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

We have a quite large monolithic app (java/spring) and we are considering splitting it up to microservices and using spring-cloud to utilize existing solution for some common problems (discovery, redundancy etc.). Currently we run one instance (with different modules) per client.

Some of our clients are small and one VPS handles it and others are larger and might use multiple servers.

The problem is that this "pack" of microservices should be isolated for each environment - they might be slightly different.

As I am reading through resources about Cloud Foundry - which looks really great - it seems that it would be best to run an cloud foundry instance per client and I am afraid that that is overkill and quite a lot of work to get one client running (which I would like to automate as much as possible).

**Ideal Solution**

**BEGIN**

We provide servers with heterogenous OS, possible containers (VM/docker/jail/...) with restrictions where they may rur and finally services with restrictions in which containers they may run.

When creating new environment I just provide list of services to run in it and the Solution creates containers, deploys services in them and sets up communication channels (message broker) between them.

It should also handle upgrades, monitoring, etc.

**END**

What approach would you recommend? Or please could you share your experience from building similar thing?

Thanks

Comment: Cloudfoundry has the concept of orgs, spaces and roles which allow sepearation. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html

Answer (score 0):

You could provide each customer with their own *space* in a single CF instance where all the microservices are deployed.